# Errors on if an elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I am a beginner at Python.

I am getting syntax errors on elif and If statements.

if "dc"=="dc":

elif  "b"== "b":

Comment: If that was all your code, you'd get an ``IndentationError`` (because Python does not like empty code blocks), not a syntax error. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: That's like saying "Nobody understands my _ because _"

Comment: check this quick sample: test_data=['if', 'elif', 'nothing']        
for test in test_data:
    if test=="if":
        print(test)
    elif test=="elif":
        print(test)
    else:
        print(test)

Comment: Empty code blocks are not allowed in Python. You have got to enter atleast one line in each code block. You can use the `pass` keyword for this. It does nothing; It just helps if the programmer doesn't know what code to enter in a code block.

Answer (score -1):

you should put some instructions within the block of the if and of course the elif

```
if something == 'my something':
    # Do something. - write your code here - what you want to do in case of something is actually equal to 'my something'
    # to just allow python compile you can reference the keyword
    pass
elif something == 'something else':
    pass
...
...
```

for next time, please provide the error python throws at you.
python exceptions (at least on 3.9+) provides excellent error exceptions that we actually can understand pretty fast.

Comment: Where your comments about ‘do something’ etc. are, use `pass` as an example that will work

Answer (score -2):

The same can be written in single line:

`value = true-expr if condition else false-expr`

if condition returns True then true-expr is assigned to value object

if condition returns False then false-expr is assigned to value object

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I have resolved the issue. It was indent issue. I thought if/elif were typed incorrectly